# Filtering content of variable with uniq command

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have

```
variable =
avi
avi
mkw
cd
dvd
```

I am trying to filter it with uniq =  to remove duplicates , i have tried it like this

```
x=`printf "$variable" | tr "\n" "," | uniq -u`
```

i want the variable look like `avi,mkw,cd,dvd but` it looks like `avi,avi,mkw,cd,dvd` = the uniq does not do its job. Being new to shell im quite confused , why does not uniq work?

Comment: u need to filter it with "uniq" before "tr"

Comment: Please show the *exact* code you use to set `variable`.

Comment: ok current directories has files e.g =a.avi , b.avi . c.mkw ,d .dvd and e.dvd
so
x=`ls | cut -d "." -f2`
variable=`printf "$x" | uniq | tr "\n" ","`

Comment: Not really related to the uniq aspect but you should use an array instead of having multiple elements inside a variable(non array).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`uniq` requires its input be sorted.

```
x=$(printf "$variable" | sort | uniq | tr "\n" ",")
```

Once you are using `sort`, however, you can simply use the `-u` flag and omit the call to `uniq`:

```
x=$(printf "$variable" | sort -u | tr "\n" ",")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ls | cut -d "." -f2 | sort | uniq | tr "\n" ","
```